# How do you upload a picture to the database taken from a smartphone's camera with php?

Tags: javascript, php, image, upload, mobile-safari

My website allows users to upload images. The upload functionality works perfectly, as long as there is a file to choose. However, when I access my website on my iPhone, and try to upload a photo, I'm given choices of choosing a file, or taking a photo with the iPhone camera. When I choose the option of taking a photo, my website crashes. Can someone help me with this?

Here's the input code:

`<input id="uploadStatus" type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFileStatus(event)" hidden>`

And here's the javascript code:

````
    reader.onload = function(){
      var output = document.getElementById('outputstatus');
      output.src = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
}; ```

Thank you in advance.
````

Comment: What do you mean by "my website crashes" exactly? Does your iPhone become unresponsive and need rebooting? Or do you just get an error message somewhere? Click [edit], and be specific: include the exact text of any error message, and the exact code and actions that triggered that error.

Comment: When I said it crashes, I meant, the web browser closes and it goes back to the screen with the icons. No error message shown.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a fault on your phone, rather than in your website, to be honest. But I don't have an iPhone, so maybe the web browser is always that unstable.

Comment: I figured it out. It was not a coding issue. It was an Xcode issue. I didn't ask for permission to access the iPhone camera or microphone. Thanks anyway.

Comment: When you figure out the answer to your own question, it's good etiquette here on StackOverflow to answer the question yourself, using an answer, not a comment. The purpose here is to help the next person with a similar question.

Comment: Sorry. In the Info section in XCode, all I did was add, "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" to the key. Then, I did another build, and it works perfectly now. I did the same thing with "Privacy - Microphone Usage Description", and the video camera is working fine also.